# Passing arrays to Flot

Tags: flot

At the end of a functioning JS I have three arrays of *x*- and *y*-coordinates, `return [theta_plot, omega_plot, e_plot];`, that I would like to send to Flot for plotting:

```
function myPlot(theta_plot, omega_plot, e_plot) {
  "use strict";
  function doPlot(position) {
    $.plot("#placeholder", [
      {
        data: theta_plot,
        label: "Angle (rad)",
        yaxis: 1,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        data: omega_plot,
        label: "Angular Velocity (rad/sec)",
        yaxis: 2,
        color: "green"
      },
      {
        data: e_plot,
        label: "Energy (J)",
        yaxis: 3,
        color: "blue"
      }
    ],
      {
        yaxes: [
          {
            font: { color: "red" }
          },
          {
            font: { color: "green" }
          },
          {
            font: { color: "blue" }
          },
          { alignTicksWithAxis: position === "left" ? 1 : null }
        ],
        legend: { position: "nw" }
      }
      );
  }
  doPlot("left");
}
```

The outer `function` is my latest attempt to pass these arrays to Flot, without success.  The inner `function` is obviously Flot.  Placing `doPlot` in my JS produces the desired result, though JSLint complains that they are not defined, as it should.  However, for purposes of organization I would like `doPlot` in my HTML.  Question: How do I make `doPlot` aware of my arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

```
function doPlot(position) {
```

with

```
function doPlot(theta_plot, omega_plot, e_plot, position) {
```

and call the new function directly without using the `myPlot()` function.